# Google Sheets IF statement with concatenated return value coming up with completely wrong answer

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula in a cell:

```
=if(D44<C44,"On track",(D44/C44)*100&"% of goal")
```

I've also tried it as

```
=if(D44<C44,"On track",concatenate((D44/C44)*100,"% of goal"))
```

I'm not getting an error message. But where I should be seeing `150% of goal` in the cell (based on my input numbers), I'm actually seeing `'85403470326% of goal`. Yes, with the apostrophe in front. I'm so lost. Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue. Please share a copy of your sheet or even a dummy sheet that can show the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(D44<C44, "On track", TEXT((D44/C44)*100, "#.00")&"% of goal")
```

or:

```
=IF(D44<C44, "On track", TEXT((D44/C44), "#.00%")&" of goal")
```

Comment: Oh wow, this did the trick! Thank you. Any idea why I was getting that weird result?

Comment: @bkula most likely dou to formatting coz TEXT() overrides it